# Link to the actual comment in my network-wide activity

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, hyperlinks, network-profile

On [this page](https://stackexchange.com/users/1703573/undo?tab=activity), under the comments subtab, there's a giant list of comments. However, they only give links like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/####`, which open the page the comment is on but don't move the page to the comment.

Could the comment ID be included in the URL such that the page opens to the comment?

Comment: Even when a comment is posted under an **answer**, the link still points to the **question**. For questions with many answers and comments, finding the one you have supposedly jumped to becomes near impossible. Site profiles already link comments correctly; the network profile should do it too. *[this is a copy of the transient bounty notice]*