# Links to comments in the Network Profile just send you to the post, and don't scroll to the specific comment

Tags: bug, comments, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I was checking [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=activity) and I noticed two things:

- Shouldn't "Activity" be renamed to "All Actions", to be in line with the main sites?
- The links to the comments just send you to the page itself, but not to the section of the page where the comment was written (the anchor)?

See an example:

> **[Grep to match all the patterns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896728)**
>
> No problem! $1 refers to the first field of the current line. I will
> add a broader explanation of the code in a while. Give a try to it and
> see if it works.

I guess that it should send you to: [Grep to match all the patterns from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896544/grep-to-match-all-the-patterns-from-a-file/28896728#comment46053544_28896728) instead of just https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896728.

Comment: Closely related to [Link to the actual comment in my network-wide activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243342/link-to-the-actual-comment-in-my-network-wide-activity) [retracted duplicate vote, because the "activity" part is new].

Comment: "all actions", rather.

Comment: @senshin This is what happens when I edit at night & don't cross-check... fixed. ;)